IntelliJ not detecting gradle implementation project
I have this gradle project with 4 subprojects inside. I use one of them as a library for the other 3. I can do a gradle build just fine, but IntelliJ doesn't detect it:
Unresolved imports
My root project's settings.gradle is the following:
rootProject.name = 'ScotlandYard-Full'
include 'scotland-yard', 'move-service', 'match-management-service', 'board-service'
project(':scotland-yard').projectDir = new File('Scotland Yard')

And it is properly reflected:
> Task :projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'ScotlandYard-Full'
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'ScotlandYard-Full'
+--- Project ':board-service'
+--- Project ':match-management-service'
+--- Project ':move-service'
\--- Project ':scotland-yard'

The way I import it is by using implementation project(':scotland-yard') in my build.gradle files. Here is a full file for context:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'se.kau.cs.sy.services'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
    implementation project(':scotland-yard')
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.1'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Here is the scotland-yard build.gradle for reference as well:
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'se.kau.cs.sy'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/se/kau/cs/sy']
        }
    }
}

processResources {
    from('src') {
        include 'se/kau/cs/sy/**'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Implementation-Title': 'Scotland Yard',
            'Implementation-Version': version
        )
    }
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Can you help me fix this please ?
So far, I've tried using implementation files('../Scotland Yard/build/libs/scotland-yard-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar') instead but this is not practical when I want to rebuild the project.
Thank you for your help !

Did you try clicking the Refresh symbol on the right side where Gradle is? This should reload the dependencies.  Other option may be to click on  File - Invalidate Caches. You can go to File - Project Structure - Libraries section to see if the libraries are there.

I didn’t mention it but tried both of this options, and none worked

I assume you have also tried to delete .build file and rebuild the project.

There is a simple example here. I hope this helps: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

It seems to work fine when I put in your source files and a couple dummy class files to test the structure.  Perhaps close IJ, then delete your .idea/ folder, and then re-open and see if it fixes things..?

Thank you for your replies, I'm not home for two days, but will test that when back and let you know !

Unfortunately, none of these worked

Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?
